# Visual Studio 2010 Sample Data generator like Expression Blend

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml, expression-blend

Is there a Visual Studio 2010 Sample Data generator like Expression Blend.

It wouldn't have to be nearly as feature-rich (nor specifically for VS2010), just as long as one could do it without typing up sample data in xaml files.

I just want a sample data generator of some sort that can generate the data in xaml data files.

Bonuses:

- friendly UI
- usable within Visual Studio 2010
- sample data works between Expression Blend 4 and VS2010 (not as important)

Comment: Doubtful.  Blend adds special MSBuild targets for the sample data so it doesn't get compiled into release assemblies.  It's much more than just creating and editing values.

Comment: @Mike Post: Yes, Blend puts each sample data file in the project's SampleData folder and marks the file's build action as "DesignData".  Modifying the build action is not an issue.